# Using ColorData function in ListPlot for a third variable

Tags: plotting, color, legending, style

I am trying plot data using a `ColorData` function to do a gradient of color from blue to red, I used `"Rainbow"` option, but something is not going well. The color gradients are not following the third variable.

Data example:

```
tab={{192,35,11},{35,16,31},{50,200,65}}
```

My code is:

```
 ListPlot[List /@ Sort[tab[[All, {1, 2}]]], AxesOrigin -> {0, -90},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 90}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", ""},
 Background -> GrayLevel[.01], PlotStyle -> (PointSize[0.03]),
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#/90] & /@ List /@ Tab[[All, 3]]),
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {10, 75}}, 
 LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, LegendLabel -> "[km/seg]", 
 LegendFunction -> "Panel"], Right], ImageSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you might want to use `Graphics` with `Blend`.

```
tab = Sort@RandomInteger[100, {20, 3}];

{c1, c2} = MinMax[tab[[All, 3]]]
(*you can define your own minimum or maximum value*)

col[c_] := Blend[{Red, Blue}, (c - c1)/(c2 - c1)]
(*color scaled between 0 and 1. You can choose any combination of colors*)

leg = BarLegend[{{Red, Blue},{c1, c2}},LegendLabel->"[km/seg]",ImageSize -> 200];
(*define the legend*)

Grid[{{Graphics[{{PointSize[Large], col[#[[3]]], Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ tab,
       Line[tab[[All, 1 ;; 2]]] (*Line is optional*)}, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200], leg}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Now it is more clear scaling data color  as you did . ColorData and ColorFunction are not so easy to understand how implementing them.

Answer (score 4):

```
tab = {{192, 35, 11}, {35, 16, 31}, {50, 200, 65}};
styledtab = Style[{#, #2}, PointSize[.03], ColorData[{"Rainbow", {10, 75}}][#3]] & @@@ tab;

ListPlot[styledtab, AxesOrigin -> {0, -90}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 250}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", ""}, Background -> GrayLevel[.01], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {10, 75}}, 
    LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, LegendLabel -> "[km/seg]", 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], Right], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Update:** Perhaps `BubbleChart` is more convenient to use with `ColorFunction`

```
BubbleChart[tab, BubbleSizes -> {0.07, .07}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {10, 75}}][#3] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, -90}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 250}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", ""}, Background -> GrayLevel[.01], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: With the black background the frame-axes are hidden (it also looks nice with a white background, +1 anyway)